# How to change/update a item from a Drawer layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

This is where i put my items inside the DrawerList and view

```
tagTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Tags);
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    items = new ArrayList<DrawerItem>();
    items.add(new DrawerItem(tagTitles[0], R.drawable.slider2));
    items.add(new DrawerItem(tagTitles[1], R.drawable.empty));

    items.add(new DrawerItem( String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.levelshow),nBases), R.drawable.empty));
    drawerList.setAdapter(new DrawerListAdapter(this, items));
    drawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0://more for here
```

This is the Drawer item

```
public class DrawerItem {
private String name;
private int iconId;

public DrawerItem(String name, int iconId) {
    this.name = name;
    this.iconId = iconId;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getIconId() {
    return iconId;
}

public void setIconId(int iconId) {
    this.iconId = iconId;
}
}
```

> DrawerListAdapter

```
public DrawerListAdapter(Context context, List objets) {
    super(context, 0, objets);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);

    }




    ImageView icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_pngg);
    TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_itemm);
    //FrameLayout foter = (FrameLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fot);
    boolean footer;
    DrawerItem item = (DrawerItem) getItem(position);
    Log.d("help", String.valueOf(name));
    name.setText(item.getName());

    icon.setImageResource(item.getIconId());
```

the case is that i want to modificate a Text from the last item, as you can see the item have a string.xml text for that item with a place holder, i need that string to be update when i want.
and i do not find the proper way to do this, please help

edit:Pertinent part of XML
                     //lots of views for here
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

```
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"

    android:divider="#4a4a4a"
    android:dividerHeight="0.56dp"
    android:background="#111"
    android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    android:headerDividersEnabled="false"

    android:stackFromBottom="false"

     />
```

Comment: put your xml also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View is updating only when You fire notifyDataSetChanged() in adapter.